# RAZOR Syntax building a menu

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am dipping in to MVC4 and Razor for the first time:
I am trying to build a menu dynamically:

```
 @foreach (var menu in Model.Menu)
 {
<li>
 Html.ActionLink("@menu.Name", "@menu.View", "@menu.Controller");
</li>
}
```

The Menu class works but the output is not a literal, but rather the string:

> Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home");  Html.ActionLink("Menu1",
>   "Index", "Menu1");  Html.ActionLink("Menu2", "Index", "Menu2");

What do I need to change to output actual literals?

EDIT: I used this as the basis for the above:

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Menu1", "Index", "Menu1")</li>
```

Menu class:

```
 public class MenuItem
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool isActive { get; set; }
        public string Controller { get; set; }
        public string View { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, as you have not set `@` before `Html.ActionLink` it was treating it as text

```
@foreach (var menu in Model.Menu)
{
    <li>
        @Html.ActionLink((string)menu.Name, (string)menu.View, (string)menu.Controller)
    </li>
}
```

Edit: Just cast it to `string` or You can try

```
@LinkExtensions.ActionLink(Html, menu.Name, menu.View, menu.Controller)
```

Comment: Using your sample I got this: CS1973: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<dynamic>' has no applicable method named 'ActionLink'

Comment: @callisto, I have tweaked answer, and please post `Menu` class

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the @ symbol before `Html.ActionLink` ***and*** remove the semicolon at the end:

```
@foreach (var menu in Model.Menu)
{
    <li>
        @Html.ActionLink(menu.Name, menu.View, menu.Controller)
    </li>
}
```

Comment: Got this error: CS1973: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<dynamic>' has no applicable method named 'ActionLink'

Comment: You also don't need the `@` symbols in front of the menu var's

Comment: I'm assuming **all** of your  menu items have values for `Name`, `View` and `Controller` properties...

Comment: I am populating the List with the correct values: <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Menu1", "Index", "Menu1")</li>
                                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Menu2", "Index", "Menu2")</li> works

Comment: In that case, I'd work backwards.  replace your variables with static text i.e. `@Html.ActionLink("Text", "Index", "Home")`.  If that runs correctly then it must be your property values.  If it still doesn't work you might have a deeper issue regarding your MVC install. P.S. No casting is required.